What is the proper name for a tree whose edges hold more than one symbols?
To supplement the title, edges from one node may hold strings with the same prefix.
For example, a node may have two edges, apple1 and apple2.
For a cardinal tree (or positional tree, PATRICIA tree), it shall be "normalized" to a compacted form, where the common prefix apple is lifted to the parent, and children nodes are labeled with strings with distinct heading character, namely 1 and 2.
But these two edges will stay the same for a tree described in my title, away from the "normalization."
I found that the term directory tree is employed to denote such a tree in some cases, but there is no consensus for such usage.
I wonder whether there is a proper name for such a tree so that I can search related researches with a concrete keyword.
